# How should I subtract two dataframes and in Pandas and diplay the required output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My table looks like this:

```
In [82]:df.head()
Out[82]:
            MatDoc  MatYr  MvT  Material  Plnt  SLoc       Batch  Customer  AmountLC  Amount ...  PO  MatYr.1  MatDoc.1  Order   ProfitCtr    SLED/BBD   PstngDate   EntryDate      Time  Username
    0   4912693062   2015  551    100062  HDC2  0001  5G30MC1A11       NaN      9.03    9.06 ... NaN      NaN       NaN    NaN  IN1165B085  26.01.2016  01.08.2015  01.08.2015  01:13:16    O33462
    1   4912693063   2015  501       166  HDC2  0004         NaN       NaN      0.00    0.00 ... NaN      NaN       NaN    NaN  IN1165B085         NaN  01.08.2015  01.08.2015  01:13:17    O33462
    2   4912693320   2015  551    101343  HDC2  0001  5G28MC1A11       NaN     53.73   53.72 ... NaN      NaN       NaN    NaN  IN1165B085  25.01.2016  01.08.2015  01.08.2015  01:16:30    O33462
```

Here, I need to group by data on `Order` column and sum only `AmountLC` column.Then I need to check for the `Order` column values such that it should be present in both `MvT101group` and `MvT102group`. and if an `Order` matches in both sets of data then I need to subtract `MvT102group` from `MvT101group`. and display

```
Order|Plnt|Material|Batch|Sum101=SumofMvt101ofAmountLC|Sum102=SumofMvt102ofAmountLC|(Sum101-Sum102)/100
```

What I have done is first I made new df containing only 101 and 102: `Mvt101` and `MvT102`

`MvT101 = df.loc[df['MvT'] == 101]`

`MvT102 = df.loc[df['MvT'] == 102]`

Then I grouped it by `Order` and got the sum value for the column

`MvT101group = MvT101.groupby('Order', sort=True)`

```
In [76]:
MvT101group[['AmountLC']].sum()
Out[76]:
Order          AmountLC
1127828     16348566.88
1127829     22237710.38
1127830     29803745.65
1127831     30621381.06
1127832     33926352.51
```

`MvT102group = MvT102.groupby('Order', sort=True)`

```
In [77]:
MvT102group[['AmountLC']].sum()
Out[77]:
Order         AmountLC
1127830       53221.70
1127831      651475.13
1127834       67442.16
1127835     2477494.17
1128622      218743.14
```

After this I am not able to understand how should I write my query.
Please ask me any further details if you want.Here is the CSV file from where I am working [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3fkUIrUyxrHdHRHSGFXWDNaQnc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understood the question correctly. After grouping both groups as you did:

```
MvT101group = MvT101.groupby('Order',sort=True).sum()
MvT102group = MvT102.groupby('Order',sort=True).sum()
```

You can update the columns' names for both groups:

```
MvT101group.columns = MvT101group.columns.map(lambda x: str(x) + '_101')
MvT102group.columns = MvT102group.columns.map(lambda x: str(x) + '_102')
```

Then merge all 3 tables so that you will have all 3 columns in the main table:

```
df = df.merge(MvT101group, left_on=['Order'], right_index=True, how='left')
df = df.merge(MvT102group, left_on=['Order'], right_index=True, how='left')
```

And then you can add the calculated column:

```
df['calc'] = (df['Order_101']-df['Order_102']) / 100
```